# Beginner C++ Question

Tags: c++, string, compiler-construction, char

I have followed the code example here

> [toupper c++ example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cctype/toupper/)

And implemented it in my own code as follows

```
void CharString::MakeUpper()
{
char* str[strlen(m_pString)];
int i=0;
str[strlen(m_pString)]=m_pString;
char* c;
while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    putchar (toupper(c));
    i++;
  }
}
```

But this gives me the following compiler error

```
CharString.cpp: In member function 'void CharString::MakeUpper()':
CharString.cpp:276: error: invalid conversion from 'char*' to 'int'
CharString.cpp:276: error:   initializing argument 1of 'int toupper(int)'
CharString.cpp: In member function 'void CharString::MakeLower()':
```

This is line 276

```
putchar (toupper(c));
```

I understand that toupper is looking for int as a parameter and returns an int also, is that the problem? If so how does the example work?

Comment: Can you give a little more clarification on what m_pString is?  Are you trying to capitalize an single array of chars (a C string) or are you capitalizing an array of strings?

Comment: Trying to capitalise every character in a single string

Comment: you are **fundamentally confused** about the use of `char` vs. `char*`; you seem to be playing it by ear.  Some serious C reading is **strongly recommended** before you proceed.

Comment: Thanks Vlad, You assume that I'm not aware of that, I'm well aware my C/C++ knowledge is next to non existent, I however dont intend on learning C++ just porting some old C++ for JNI use. If you have good links to reading material then please do share them though. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go with the assumption that m_pString is a C style string (char *).  You're doing way more fiddling than you need to be doing.

```
void CharString::MakeUpper()
{
   char* str = m_pString; // Since you're not modifying the string, there's no need to make a local copy, just get a pointer to the existing string.
   while (*str) // You can use the string pointer as an iterator over the individual chars
   {
      putchar (toupper(*str)); // Dereference the pointer to get each char.
      str++;   // Move to the next char (you can merge this into the previous line if so desired, but there's no need.
   }
}
```

In the example you cite, the reason it works is because of how the variables are declared.

```
int main ()
{
  int i=0;
  char str[]="Test String.\n";  // This is a compile time string literal, so it's ok to initialize the array with it.  Also, it's an array of `char`s not `char*`s.
  char c;  // Note that this is also a `char`, not a `char *`
  while (str[i])
  {
    c=str[i];
    putchar (toupper(c));
    i++;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Because of the error-prone ways of using C strings, your best bet is std::string:

```
void CharString::MakeUpper()
{
   string str(m_pString);
   transform(str.begin(), str.end(), ostream_iterator<char>(cout), &toupper);
}
```

Comment: Actually it was quite wrong - `while (str)` should be `while (*str)`.  You don't advance until the pointer is `NULL`, you advance until the character being pointed at is `'\0'`.  See corrected version above.  All the more reason to stay away from C string and use `std::string`.

Comment: Using string has introduced a whole load of new compiler errors :( I included <string.h> but I get string is not defined errors

Comment: @donal:  `<String.h>` is deprecated, you need to include `<string>` to get `std::string`, `<algorithm>` to get `std::transform`, `<iterator>` to get `ostream_iterator` and `<iostream>` to get `cout`.  This seems like a lot, but you can put these into the precompiled header of your project.  You're also going to have to either use the namespace prefix `std::` - e.g. `std::string`, `std::algorithm`, `std::ostream_iterator`, or else add `using namespace std;` in your cpp file after you include your headers.  (Don't put it in a header, or you could be in for a world of trouble.)

Answer (score 4):

Also,

```
char* str[strlen(m_pString)];
int i=0;
str[strlen(m_pString)]=m_pString;
```

is not valid C++ - arrays must be dimensioned using compile time constants - this is a C99 feature. And I really don't think the code would do what you want it to, even if it were legal, as you seem to be accessing one past the end of the array. It would be handy if you posted the complete class definition.

Comment: arrays must be dimensioned using compile time constants -- interesting.  Is this coming in a new C++ spec?

Comment: @WhirlWind It's always been the case. It is not changed in C++0x.

Comment: @WhirlWind:  That's how C++ has always been and how C was prior to C99.  There was no impetus to change this in the upcoming C++ standard, because `std::vector<>` will handle variable lengths and do more.

Comment: I had always thought there was some effort to make C++ more or less a stronger-typed superset of C... interesting to see the divergence here.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think your code does what you want it to do and in fact if it compiled it would explode.

```
char* str[strlen(m_pString)]; // you've made an array of X C strings where 
                              // X is the length of your original string.
int i=0;


str[strlen(m_pString)]=m_pString; // You've attempted to assign the C string in your array
                                  // at location X to point at you m_pString.  X is the
                                  // same X as before and so is 1 past the end of the array
                                  // This is a buffer overrun.
```

I think what you actually wanted to do was to copy the content of m_pString into str.  You'd do that like so:

```
char * str = new char[strlen(m_pString)];
memcpy(str, m_pString); // I may have the operands reversed, see the docs.
```

The easier way to do this though is to stop using C strings and to use C++ strings:

```
std::string str = m_pString;
```

There are more issues, but this should get you steer you more toward the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

You need to feed toupper() an int (or a char) instead of a char *, which is how you've declared c.

try:

```
char c;
```

Also,

```
char* str[strlen(m_pString)];
```

is an an array of pointers to characters, not just a single string.

This line:

```
str[strlen(m_pString)]=m_pString;
```

is an assignment to a bad pointer then, since there was no allocation.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a built-in conversion from `char *` to `int`, which is why the error occurs.  Since you're trying to capitalize a character, you need to dereference the pointer.

`putchar(toupper(*c));`

Comment: @Matt, this is but the tip of the iceberg.  He's using `char*` everywhere he should have used `char`.